# Free hand line drawing in ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net-ajax, asp.net-3.5, line-drawing

How can I draw free hand lines above a image in ASP.NET 3.5 AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

sort of tricky but lets try:

```
create canvas object
position it over image
track mouse movement
draw arcs, lines over canvas
```

Yes this is sorta marketing or management kind of view but there is something to start with ;)

Comment: would have gladly given it if I had and seriously am a bit busy to try it, so you will have to do it yourself :)

Comment: Canvas Object? in ASP.Net? I don't think so.